# three divs next to each other with two rows (six divs in total). if I do float they all go in one row

Tags: css, html, row

So I got a question about DIVs. I want 2 rows with 3 divs in each, centered. But the problem is if I do clear: left; all 6 will be next o eachother. Here is how my code looks like right now and I hope you can help me out.

CSS:

```
.row1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 270px;
}
.row2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 270px;
}

.columns {
  width: 190px;
  height: 274;
  border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-right: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
 }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="row1">
  <div class="columns"> </div>
  <div class="columns"> </div>
  <div class="columns"> </div>
</div>

<div id="row2">
  <div class="columns"> </div>
  <div class="columns"> </div>
  <div class="columns"> </div>
</div>
```

this is one div:

#### head text

paragraph text

Comment: add clear: both for #row2

Comment: change .row2/.row1 to #row2/#row1 and remove the `position: absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/VcY6X/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use "display: inline-block" instead of float and remove "position: absolute". Add closing divs for the columns. And change css for the rows to refer to id, not class.

**CSS:**

```
.columns {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 190px;
  border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-right: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
}

#row1 {
  height: 270px;
}
#row2 {
  height: 270px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="row1">
  <div class="columns">1.1</div>
  <div class="columns">1.2</div>
  <div class="columns">1.3</div>
</div>

<div id="row2">
  <div class="columns">2.1</div>
  <div class="columns">2.2</div>
  <div class="columns">2.3</div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5vKH/1/

Comment: this is the same as my answer. plus if you don't give `text-align: center` it won't be centered.

Comment: @Pr0xyius and it is a bad practice to repeat the same css with id selectors for different elements. css classes are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

They are all floating next to each other. You should add a clear row where you want to seperate them. We usually call it clearfix.

```
<style>
.clearfix{ clear:both; }
</style>

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="row2">
```